# Как вы успеваете оставаться на волне

Tags: frontend

Нашёл планы по развитию ангуляра. Теперь он будет выходить раз в пол года. через 2 года нас ждёт уже ангуляр 7.
То же самое с redux. Какой бы курс или книга не вышли, они уже устаревают. Кто нибудь успевает пересаживаться на новую мажорную версию, держать в голове несколько версий фреймворка, нескольких фреймворков. Есди да, то сколько времени в сутки вы уделяете самообразованию и какими материалами пользуетесь: вебинары, документация официальная, статьи, видеокурсы.

Comment: Поэтому учите английский и читайте оригинальную документацию сразу после выхода обновлений. И всегда будете на волне всего.

Comment: Не всем дано успевать осознавать..

Comment: Ну, я не на волне. Я пишу код ES5, вебпак/гулп не использую, почти любые сторонние библиотеки вроде жквери, реакта или того же ангуляра презираю, а мои сайты неплохо работают на IE8. И ничего, мне норм, работа есть даже для таких как я :)

Comment: фундаментальные знания практически не устаревают. а нюансы новых API знать не так уж и важно. если вы понимаете принципы положенные в основу redux, то разберетесь с ним быстро.